# systemd: Failed to start Create System Users

Tags: arch-linux, systemd

After upgrading and rebooting my Arch system, I notice the following in journalctl output:

```
systemd[1]: Failed to start Create System Users.
```

I see the same thing reported by `systemctl --failed`:

```
● systemd-sysusers.service loaded failed failed Create System Users
```

It may or may not have been present before the upgrade.

Searching for this message did not turn up any results. Does anyone know the reason for it and the solution?

Comment: You are the one with the logs on your machine.  You tell us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, journalctl revealed that I had an error in /etc/gshadow.

My issue was resolved by running:

```
grpck
```

Comment: For me, it was because I was using command substitution to "*paste*" a command doing `bcp /dev/sdb | gzip > /mnt/windows.gz` , i.e , backing up a compressed image of my windows drive, which I ran as `$(clip p)` , where `clip p` was supposed to write the command to stdout. For some *strange* reason, it interpreted the `|` as the destination file rather than the pipe operator, writing until my disk was totally full. It failed and said so, but I only noticed this on next boot  when this prompt came. I ran your *helpful* command , and it said no free space, which is how i realised

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, and for anyone coming here at a later date , it's *possible* that your disk is *full to the brim*. That will also cause this (and many other issues) that won't show up on *dmesg*. Also, if you wish to know what is `bcp` or `clip` , these are programs I've written , they're at my github : https://github.com/a-p-jo